# Using Java Regex to Replace every characters starting from a particular char in line

Tags: java, regex

How to replace every single characters, till the end of a line, using Java regex?

For Example: I want to replace every character with XXX right after = sign

contact.name=**Stack Overflow**

contact.name=**XXX**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String example = "contact.name=Stack Overflow";
example = example.replaceAll("=.*", "=XXX");
```

Comment: .replaceAll("=.*", "=XXX"); would be sufficient. The braces are redundant.

Comment: Ah this worked perfectly. Just what I looked for. Thank you for both of you, Oscar and Mana.

Comment: @azeemigi Please consider accepting the answer that was most helpful for you :) (mark the check to its left)

Comment: @Oscar I checked this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of it

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("=(.*?)\n").matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
    string = string.substring(0, string.length - matcher.group(1).length);
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.group(1).length; i ++) {
        string += "X";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yikes, why not use `replaceAll`?

Comment: Sorry, added too much complication. I thought we were after replacing *each character with exactly one X*.

Comment: Hmm, I can understand why you thought that, the original question isn't quite clear.

Comment: Yes I understand. My question wasn't clear. Thank you @MiladNaseri for your prompt answer. The answer I expected was this [=.*].

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad you've found your answer

Comment: I actually was looking for how to replace *each character with exactly one X*, and this was the top search result and helped me. I was hoping there was some way to do it with replaceAll, but I guess not.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It feels good to know I was of some help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String ex = "contact.name=Stack Overflow";
ex = ex.replaceAll("=\w+(.*)", "=XXX");
```