# How to replace word after : in this situation

Tags: java

I have

```
String a="4:1 6:24 8:3 10:44 20:4 23:5 28:6"
```

How can I replace all characters after `:`?

In the end, I want `a="4;6;8;10;20;23;28;"`

I only know how to do with one

```
a.substring(0, a.indexOf(":")).trim() + ";"
```

But this code only replaces all data after `:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Java Regex to Replace every characters starting from a particular char in line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871701/using-java-regex-to-replace-every-characters-starting-from-a-particular-char-in)

Comment: Alternatively, call `split()` with space as the delimiter, which will give you an array of strings that have the form `value:value`, and then iterate over the array, replacing the way you alredy know, and add the result of each replacement to a string

Comment: `a.replaceAll("\\:\\d+ *", ";")`

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
String a = "4:1 6:24 8:3 10:44 20:4 23:5 28:6";
String b = a.replaceAll(":[0-9]*[ ]?",";");

System.out.println(b);
```

Output

```
4;6;8;10;20;23;28;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream API to achieve that.

```java
String a="4:1 6:24 8:3 10:44 20:4 23:5 28:6";
String result = Arrays.stream(a.split(" "))
                      .map(s -> s.split(":")[0])
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
4;6;8;10;20;23;28
```

Explanation

- `a.split(" ")` will split string into tokens where delimiter is space
- `map(s -> s.split(":")[0])` will take every token, splits it on `:` and return only first part
- `collect(Collectors.joining(";"))` will join all tokens using field separator `;`